# Creating a "tree" or directory structure from a object of (possibly circular) relations

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, tree

Given a object whose keys are projects and values are dependencies. I've been trying to assemble a nested tree structure without any represented circular dependencies (think files and folders).

Here's a simple example:

```
{
  'a': ['b'],
  'b': ['c'],
  'c': [],
}
```

This would create:

```
{
  'a': {
    'b': {
      'c': {}
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the "rules":

1. any dependency that is not used by any other dependency should be at the top of the tree
2. any dependency with only one use should be nested within that dependnecy and so on
3. any dependency that is used by 2 or more dependencies it should be placed as a sibling of the highest node

Here's a more complex example:

```
{
  'a': ['b', 'q'],
  'b': ['c', 'f'],
  'c': ['d'],
  'p': ['o'],
  'o': [],
  "d": [],
  'e': ['c'],
  "q": []
}
```

should be:

```
{
  'a': {
    'b': 
      "f": {},
    },
    'q': {},
  },
  "p": {
    'o': {},
  },
  "c": { // note this would first get put ito b, but because its used by e it becomes a sibling of the highest node
    "d"; {}
  },
  "e": {}
}
```

I've tried a bunch of solutions from working with nested dot keys to using full on `class Node` instances because of the circularity I keep runing into maximum call stack issues.

I'm also stuck becasuse of the nature of building up a node to have it relocate somewhere else in the tree.

I know this is a really open-ended problem but I'm wondering if there's a simpler solution or way of thinking about it.

Answer (score 2):

I would first identify the children that have multiple parents: collect all the array members into a single array and identify the duplicates in it.

Then identify the keys that should be toplevel keys in the result: those are the keys that do not occur as children, or are duplicates among them.

You could then use a depth first traversal and create a node object for every visited key. Do not not create node entries for duplicates, except at the top level.

```js
const exclude = (arr, omitSet) => arr.filter(val => !omitSet.has(val));

const duplicateSet = (arr) =>
    new Set(arr.filter(function (val) {
        return !this.delete(val);
    }, new Set(arr)));


function toNested(data) {
    const nodes = {};
    const descendants = Object.values(data).flat();
    const withMultipleParents = duplicateSet(descendants);
    const withSingleParents = new Set(exclude(descendants, withMultipleParents));
    const withNoParents = [...exclude(Object.keys(data), withSingleParents), ...withMultipleParents];
    
    function dfs(key) {
        if (nodes[key]) return nodes[key];
        nodes[key] = {};
        for (const child of data[key] ?? []) {
            if (withSingleParents.has(child)) nodes[key][child] = dfs(child);
        }
        return nodes[key];
    }

    return Object.fromEntries(withNoParents.map(key => [key, dfs(key)]));
}

const data = {'a': ['b', 'q'],'b': ['c', 'f'],'c': ['d'],'p': ['o'],'o': [],"d": [],'e': ['c'],"q": []};

console.log(toNested(data));
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't match the expected output.  `c` should end up a sibling of `a`.

Comment: Indeed, I missed half of the question there. Updated my answer to take all the requirements into account.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a graph, this seems like a two part solution since you have possible circular dependencies that you wont know about until the entire object is parsed. After you create the graph you can begin recursively popping off nodes and adding them to the new object.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
digraph {
    a -> b  a -> q
    b -> c [color=red]  b -> f
    c -> d
    p -> o
    d
    e -> c [color=red]
    q
    // Z->a Z->c Z->e Z->p
}
```

First drop duplicate connections (red)
Second, build the graph
Third, add all parentless to root node

https://tsplay.dev/m3v71N

```
// convert to edge array for simplicity
const edges = Object.entries(data).flatMap(([k, v]) => v.map(e => [k, e]))
console.log(edges)

// list all nodes
let nodes = Object.entries(data).flat(2)
nodes = Array.from(new Set(nodes)).sort()
console.log(nodes)

// filter out red edges
const goodEdges = edges.filter((a) => edges.filter(b => b[1] === a[1]).length === 1)
console.log(goodEdges)

// add root edges to missing node
nodes.map(e => goodEdges.find(a => a[1] === e) || goodEdges.push(['$', e]))
console.log(goodEdges)

// create nodes
let nodeInstances = Object.fromEntries(nodes.map(e => [e, {} as Record<string, any>]))
nodeInstances.$ = {};
console.log(nodeInstances)

// build tree
goodEdges.map(e => nodeInstances[e[0]][e[1]] = nodeInstances[e[1]])

// return tree
console.log(nodeInstances.$)
```

Comment: This is amazing work, very insightful I can learn a lot from just this. However it's not a complete solution. It doesn't handle circular cases, and it doesn't follow rule #3 currently if a project is used in multiple places aka a bad edge it's put at the root, not the highest node sibling. tests here https://gist.github.com/reggi/0d45b062787a998d3ffeb63884f32e9f

Comment: Your solution helped me arrive at the answer, expanded on it to account for circularity and hoisting. Check out my answer if your curious, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

OP here  this was a very big question I kind of just dropped on StackOverflow and there was a ton of helpful comments and answers. I dug deeper into graphs and nodes and using some of the bits and pieces from answers here I was able to arrive at what I was looking for. It's available on github / deno as a typescript module.

- Github: https://github.com/reggi/tree_lint
- Deno:
  https://deno.land/x/tree_lint@0.0.3

The core logic looks something like this ([source](https://github.com/reggi/tree_lint/blob/main/process_deps/mod.ts)), there's a lot going on here please check out the full source for details, but as the comments suggest you need to build up the tree, remove the unwanted nodes that are circular and the ones you will hoist and "re-parent" them. A lot of good learnings here.

```
export const runEdges = (edges: Edge[]) => {
  const uniqueNodes = getUniqueNodes(edges)
  const nodesCache = getNodesCache(uniqueNodes, edges)
  const nodes = Object.values(nodesCache)
  const tree = getTree(uniqueNodes)
  const rootNodes = nodes.filter(node => node.isRoot).map(toNode)
  const circularNodes = nodes.filter(node => node.isCircular).map(toNode)
  const circularBinaryExtraEdges = nodes.map(node => node.circularBinaryExtraEdges).flat()
  const reparentNodes = nodes.filter(node => node.needsReparenting)
  const rootEdges = rootNodes.map(toRootNode)
  const removeEdgesThatPointToRoot = (e: Edge) => !rootNodes.includes(e[1])
  const removeEdgesWhereParentAndChildAreCircular = (e: Edge) => !(circularNodes.includes(e[0]) && circularNodes.includes(e[1]))
  const treeEdges: Edge[] = [
    ...edges
      .filter(removeEdgesThatPointToRoot)
      .filter(removeEdgesWhereParentAndChildAreCircular),
    ...circularBinaryExtraEdges,
    ...rootEdges
  ]
  const firstTree = buildTree(tree, treeEdges)
  const newEdges = findReparentEdges(firstTree, reparentNodes)
  const secondTree = deleteNodesFromParents(firstTree, reparentNodes)
  const thirdTree = buildTree(secondTree, newEdges)
  return thirdTree.$
}
```

Special thanks to everyone who commented or answered this question. ❤️